# How to write a background multiple sh run in a perl script? (tried several methods but all failed)

Tags: perl, shell, background

I tried to write a background multiple sh run in a perl script, below is my 3 tries:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < @num - 1; $i++ ) {
    $num1 = $num[ $i + 1 ] - 1;

    `nohup sh ./tmpScript/matrixR.$num[$i]-$num1.sh &`
    # Don't know why not background run........just run one by one and i have to wait.........
}
```

Tried:

```
`sh *.sh &`     
#Wrong    ........just run one by one and i have to wait.........
```

Also tried:

```
`cd tmpScript; for file in *.sh; do nohup sh \$file \&; done `;  
#Still wrong........just run one by one and i have to wait.........
```

They all failed..Could any of you help and solve it? Thanks!

p.s.: "``" these marks didn't displayed above..(seemed be eaten by stackoverflow, it's my first time asking..)

Comment: Backticks are code formatting markers on SO. You can avoid this by indented linefeed then 4 spaces. 
Please can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? There's not many reasons to try and background processes spawned via backticks from a perl script...

Comment: I have amended your formatting - could you have a look to make sure I haven't broken it - hopefully it was just the formatting.

Comment: What makes you think the first doesn't work???

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for reminding! I found a bug that avoiding the follow scripts running...The first method 'works' now..but still just screen print "nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout/n
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout/n
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout/n"    like this 7 times but with nothing running at background. Although now I could submit these 7 jobs manually, I consider one day eventually I'll run something more than I can manually submitted..

Comment: So the program did get executed (since it created output) and there's no reason to believe it wasn't executed in the background. So your diagnosis is inaccurate. Perhaps your script is having an error, but you discard the error messages without reading them. `system("nohup sh ./tmpScript/matrixR.$num[$i]-$num1.sh &")` would make more sense, and the output will be in `nohup.out` by default.

Answer (score 1):

So, given your problem seems to be:

invoke `sh ./tmpScript/matrixR.$num[$i]-$num1.sh &` multiple times in parallel.

My first thought would be that it's worth having a look at that script, because perl can probably do it too.

However for the general case I would suggest using [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parallel::ForkManager):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Parallel::ForkManager;
my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager->new(30);

for ( $i = 0; $i < @num - 1; $i++ ) {
    $num1 = $num[ $i + 1 ] - 1;

    $manager->start and next;
    exec("./tmpScript/matrixR.$num[$i]-$num1.sh >/dev/null")
       or die($!);
}

$manager->wait_all_children();
```

This has the added advantage that it'll parallelise 30 times, but wait until sup processes complete before continuing. Which means you don't denial-of-service your server.

Comment: Improved to avoid superfluous process.